# данные не передаются через POST из JS

Tags: javascript, php

```
var massa = $('.summa').val();
    var summa = $('.netto').val();
    $.post(
        "https://mysite/wp-content/themes/zip_theme/page-telegramcart.php",
                { 

                    "cart" : cart,
                    "cart1" : cart1,
                    "cartprice" : cartprice,
                    "cartpricemin" : cartpricemin,
                    "cartplits" : cartplits,
                    "cartplits1" : cartplits1,
                    "cartPlitsprice" : cartPlitsprice,
                    "cartPlitspricemin" : cartPlitspricemin,
                    "cartvtul" : cartvtul,
                    "cartvtul1" : cartvtul1,
                    "cartpriceVtul" : cartpriceVtul,
                    "cartpriceVtulmin" : cartpriceVtulmin,
                    "kolichestvo" : kolichestvo,
                    "massa" : massa,
                    "summa" : summa


                },
            function(data){
                    if (data==1){
                        document.location.href = "https://mysite/thanks";

                    }
                else {

                    document.location.href = "https://mysite/page-telegramcart.php";


                }
                }

        );
```

Данные беру из localStorage.
в файл PHP ничего не передается даже пустое значение.
Что делаю не так?

Comment: А точно все эти переменные, который в объекте на передачу, проинициализированны? По синтаксису ошибок вроде нет, остаётся вариант, что что-то не так с переменными.

Comment: Да , все инициализированно. Причем интересно что PHP даже ошибку не дает что такой переменной не найдено на которую я ссылаюсь на PHP странице куда передаю переменные.

Comment: @roman-bush Странно, но method передается как GET, а не POST. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать полную форму аякс-запроса, а не сокращённую.

Comment: как минимум в инструментах разработчика в браузере можно посмотреть что и куда отправляется. чтобы уже быть уверенным в этой части процесса. там же можно сделать запрос в нужное место и с нужными параметрами, изменив существующий